# Vue Router - Nested Routes Not Working as Expected

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-router4

I'm trying to create a simple nested routing:

- **App** (root component, main navigation)
- **Topic1** (sub-navigation)

  - **Topic1/Sub**
- **Topic2**

My [demo on Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/affectionate-architecture-422k6?file=/src/App.vue) has the following issues:

### **1.** When navigating from `/topic1` to `/topic1/sub`, I expected the content from `topic1` to show up and the content from `topic1/sub` to be shown below, like this:

[image: Expected result]

However, `Topic 1` does not show anymore.

### **2.** How can I avoid showing "App" twice?

[image: Unexpected result]

I know I've added `path: "/topic1", component: App,` but only because without it the routing did not work at all. As per the comments in `router/index.js`:

```js
component: App, // Option 1 - Navigation to topic1,2 and /sub works (why?) 'App' is displayed twice
component: Topic1, // Option 2 - Navigation to /sub does not work but at least 'App' is only displayed once
```

I seem to be missing something essential - thank you already for any answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`App` component is showing twice because it is mounted twice. First it is mounted in `main.js` when you create the `app`. Then it is mounted in `router-view` as the route component. To avoid this, you shouldn't use the `App` component in router, instead make another Layout component where you define the page layout to be used by the `vue-router`. Also, this will allow the scenario where, while having a single entry point for your app (App), you can define different layouts for different routes, if needed.

Regarding the first question, the content of `Topic1` component is not shown when navigating to Sub route, because it is wrapped in `router-view`. `router-view` displays only the content of the current route component. Avoid placing any content in `router-view` as it will be replaced on route navigation. This will work:

```html
<h1>Topic1</h1>

<h2>Topic1 Content</h2>
<p>
    <router-link to="/topic1/Sub">/topic1/sub</router-link>
</p>
<router-view> </router-view>
```

Here is the [working codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/youthful-snow-1m2uk?file=/src/views/Layout.vue).
Also I refactored a bit your router `index.js`.

Comment: Thank you, Igor, this is working perfectly. Indeed, the indentation was off in my example Also, I did not consider that I needed another wrapper (Layout) - with this in mind, routing now works as expected.